# ReferenceError: require is not defined :require('./config/passport')(passport);

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Trying to initialize passport and now getting this.
ReferenceError: require is not defined

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const URL = createRequire(import.meta.url);
import passport from 'passport'


import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.js'
import loginRoutes from './routes/login.js'

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ES `import` and npm `require()` at the same time

Try this

```js
import { passport } from "./config/passport"
```

Or change all import of the project to `require()` ( Highly not recommended )

Comment: Ok, how do you import then do you know?

Comment: Okay I'll edit the answer and put the code there

Comment: That would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

in your main entry point file eg `app.js`

pull in your passport config passing app.

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
require('./src/config/passport')(app);
```

Your config file eg:`passport.js` should look like this

```
import passport from 'passport';

require('./strategies/local.strategy')(); //Or whatever strategy you are using

const passportConfig = (app) => {
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  // stores user to session
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });

  // retrieves user from session
  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
};
```